# How to create a stopwatch timer without using "chronometer" class and just by using"SystemClock"--Android Phone App Developement

Tags: java, android, sdk, timertask, chronometer

How can we write a stopwatch timer similar to the following (with the same functionality) without using chronometer class and solely by using "SystemClock" class? Most of the examples I have seen so far are either just using chronometer class or a combination of both. Thanks for your hints:

```
package com.example.stopwatch;
import com.example.stopwatch.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button start;
    private Button stop;
    private Button reset;

    private Chronometer mydChronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uI();
    }

    public void uI() {
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstart);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btreset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);
        mydChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == start) {
            mydChronometer.start();

        } else if (v == stop) {

            mydChronometer.stop();
        } else if (v== reset) {
            mydChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you can use Timer and timerTask to achieve this

Comment: but why not want to use chronometer?

Comment: It is the project specification! I should obey! I might consider timerTask though!

Comment: dont use a TimerTask, it creates useless Thread behind, use a Handler instead